# Forest Classification with multispectral imagery

Tags: image-processing, classification, arcgis

How can I classify forest cover into stratified classes of forest canopy density with 12-band sentinel-2 data?

I am attempting use recent sentinel-2 [data](http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/29/P/MK/2016/12/27/0/) to classify all forest over 5m in height. If it is possible I would also like canopy density (as a metric for percentage tree cover) however I am not sure how feasible this is without control points on the ground.

I have read that it is possible to use the shadowing in the panchromatic band in conjunction with the NIR and IR bands to determine depth but this does not appear available with Sentinel-2.

I have completed forest inventory before utilizing LiDar and on another occasion with multi-spectral imagery, ground control points and object based classification. However I have never attempted it using solely multi-spectral imagery.

A [method](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7876b225f8034a0ebba79fad4afb80ad) has been developed previously which used multispectral satellite imagery from the [Landsat 7] thematic mapper plus (ETM+) sensor and a supervised learning algorithm to determine tree cover but details regarding the finer points of the method are scant.

I am unfortunately limited to Arc 10 [Advanced Licence] with just the Spatial Analyst and Geo-statistical Analyst extensions.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: and what is the question?